# 2000's RPG PC game

Tags: identify-this-game

I've been looking for a certain game, I think it's from the 2000's.

I can only remember a few characteristics:

- It was an RPG game.
- There was a cave, with what I think was a sleeping dragon and there was lava blocking the way to it.
- In the city, it had a tavern with a knife minigame, the target had 3 weels and the objective was to line up the same block color in a column.
- There was a port, with a ladder, that let you dive in the ocean.
- In the game map, in the oceanic part, had warnings that in certain parts lived sea monsters.
- In some part of the city, uphill, was a gate or portal that at a certain point lead you to talk to Merlin.
- You could cast spells everywhere but sometimes the citizens got enraged and would hunt you.
- the game was not 2d graphics.

Comment: Welcome to Retrocomputing Stack Exchange. Please read the [tour]. This is scraping along the upper end of [what constitutes "retro"](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2/278), so might be closed or migrated.

Comment: Sorry i didn't find any stackexchange that could fit with my question, this one was the closest i found.

Comment: Are you sure the game was for the PC? The story items sound very close to *Beyond the Beyond* for the PlayStation.

Comment: Yes i'm 100% sure whas on pc.

Comment: @PabloBrodt I suspect that it might be a better fit for [gaming.se] but we'll move it there if that turns out to be the case. No need for you to do anything but try to remember some more (though this seems like enough information already!).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 Arqade doesn't want identification questions unless it's asking to identify a screenshot or audio clip. If this post isn't on-topic here then I'm pretty sure it's not on-topic anywhere in the StackExchange network.

Comment: @RossRidge Thanks for pointing that out. I knew that there was a limitation to the identification questions that Arqade accepted, but I didn't remember that it was that broad.

Comment: Here in retrocompuing, [RPG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_RPG) isn't a game :-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I cant believe I found it, I'm so happy right now, years and years trying...

The name of the game is Quest for Glory V.

Here is some gameplay: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vtx_fpdi06w

And down here the image that finally helped me to find the game:

[image: Quest for Glory V]
<sub>(source: [akamaized.net](https://gamefaqs.akamaized.net/screens/f/4/3/gfs_41400_2_47.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Great news! How did you find it?